# Is there any way to run non UI test cases using protractor

Tags: protractor

I have test cases which are REST based and i want to run them using protractor but without launching browser. So is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you want to use protractor if your tests are non UI testcases? What would be the advantage for you?

Comment: Protractor is an end-to-end test framework. It uses the UI to do actions like a user would. Maybe look into writing a Jasmine test.

Comment: @cnishina Actually the test framework which we are using is protractor + jasmine. So the requirement for us is to write both UI and REST based test cases. I have used jasmine to write the REST test case but wanted to use protractor because I had a trouble in adding the reporter to the pure jasmine tests.